# Does normal SSL do the job when a page is accessed via mobile device? (iPhone, Android etc)

Tags: ssl, mobile-website

I have installed ssl on my server, but I was wondering if there is anything specific I need to do to make sure the connection is encrypted when a user connects via mobile devices such as iPhone / iPad, Android and other tablets. Correct me if I am wrong, but as long as the browser used supports SSL this should be fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a policy to your server such that you only accept SSL connections. Therefore any device or browser which does not suppor or correctly negotiate a valid SSL connection will be denied access.

Without knowing what web server you're using, it is diffiult to be any more specific. However, there is some useful information of how to enforce this in Apache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98593/restrict-apache-to-only-allow-access-using-ssl-for-some-directories)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it should be fine. SSL is a negotiation between the Server and the client's web browser. Yes, you are right, as long as the browser supports SSL you should be fine :)

Hope it helps :)